# How to define "INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY" column with node-pg-migrate?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, database-migration, dbmigrate, node-pg-migrate

How do I define a migration file using node-pg-migrate for the below table

```
CREATE TABLE color (
    color_id INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    color_name VARCHAR NOT NULL
);
```

There seems to be no documentation on how to do INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS INDENTITY column using node-pg-migrate

Comment: or even generated by default as identity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't checked the history or when `sequenceGenerated` has been added, but at least at the time of writing the SQL you seek for can be generated with

```
pgm.createTable(
  'color',
  {
    color_id: {
      type: 'integer',
      sequenceGenerated: {
        precedence: 'ALWAYS'
      }
    },
    color_name: {
      type: 'varchar',
      notNull: true
    }
  }
)
```

This will create a migration with SQL

```
CREATE TABLE "color" (
  "color_id" integer GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
  "color_name" varchar NOT NULL
);
```